# How to avoid a function to be called twice when the state changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this react component

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState(valueFromProps);
const [value, setValue] = useState(valueFromProps);

const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
  if (initialRender.current) {
    initialRender.current = false;
  } else {
    console.log("set new value");
    const newValue = calculateNewValue(filter);
    setvalue(() => newValue);
  }
}, [filter]);

const getReports = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  //generate some html
};

return (
  <>
    <div>
      {getReports(value)}
    </div>
  </>
);
```

pretty standard. It works as expected, the only problem is that **getReports** is executed twice every time the state **filter** changes. The first time with the old value and the second time with the new value.

I put some console.log and I can see the function is called twice despite the log in useEffect is printed only once.

What can I do to make it run only once please?

Comment: May be you could try wrapping it within `useCallback` and adding `value` as a dependency? That way, only when the `value` changes, the function will execute. Something like so: `const getReports = useCallback((value) => { console.log('function called'); }, [value]);`

Comment: tried but same result

Comment: This happens because that's React behavior. After filter state update, first react runs return statement where getReports called and then runs side effects in useEffect where state updated again, this time value. Re-render runs again. If your one state depends on another, just update value in same place you set your filter (run setFilter and setValue in same function).  React will batch state updated and render only once. You can remove useEffect. Another way, use useMemo for value instead of useState.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but maybe because of `setvalue(() => newValue);`, the callback here is used to make updates after the state is changed so `setFilter` ran and after that `setvalue(() => newValue)` <-- this

try: `setvalue(calculateNewValue(filter));`

Comment: that didn't work sorry

Comment: ohh,
what is your react version? in v18 `useEffect` runs twice in strictmode, try to remove `<React.StrictMode>` from index.js file
Add `console.count("useEffect");` to `useEffect` to check that and also there is typo in `setvalue(() => ...` should be camelcase --> `setValue(() => newValue);`

Answer (score 0):

React runs return statement after filter state update and only then runs useEffect, which itself updates state and triggers re-render.

I would suggest update your state in same place you update your filter or use useMemo for value if it only depends on filter state.

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState(valueFromProps);
const [value, setValue] = useState(valueFromProps);

const getReports = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  //generate some html
};

cons updateFilter = (filter) => {
  setFilter(filter);
  setValue(calculateNewValue(filter);
}

return (
  <>
    <div>
      {getReports(value)}
    </div>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the solution proposed by @Andyally doesn't work, thanks to his suggestion I came up with a solution using **useMemo**

```
let value = props.value;
const [filter, setFilter] = useState(valueFromProps);

value = useMemo(() => calculateNewValue(filter), [filter]);

const getReports = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  //generate some html
};

return (
  <>
    <div>
      {getReports(value)}
    </div>
  </>
);
```